# Are Magnum Mini halal?

Tags: halal-haram

A friend told me that Magnum Mini are not halal just because they say suitable for vegetrain. upon googling I found [this](https://thehalallife.co.uk/products/magnum/) link. not sure of the source but It is confusing because the label says (Soya) in brackets next to E471 whereas other ice cream doesn't mention E471 at all.

Comment: Contact thee manufacturers for the most accurate information. Ingredients can be changed so its possible websites that say they are halal may have incorrect information and the same vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I contact Magnum/walls and asked if E471 is vegan/halal and they said no, and I inquired about the source as of which animal to which they had no idea. They also mentioned they sell halal and/or vegan written on it.